# How to select build configuration x86/x64 in Eclipse (C++)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

As the title says: How to select build configuration x86/64 in Eclipse?
Is that even possible?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: MinGW unfortunately.

Comment: Are you asking how to compile for either 32bit or 64 bit? Isn't that a compiler option which you then can set by right clicking on your project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > C++ Compiler and then set by adding to (if non other fits) the "Miscellaneous" field? Or maybe with MinGW you need separate MinGW installs for 32 / 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build configuration is not normally part of the selection within Eclipse C++ (CDT). But rather it is based on the toolchain Eclipse uses.

Put a gcc for x86_64 on your PATH and Eclipse will use it by default.

If on the other hand you want to do Cross compilation, create a *Cross GCC* project and provide the specific prexix/path for your compilation.

In the Wizard:

[image]

In the project settings:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, where exactly did you explicitly select x86 vs x64?

Comment: You don't you install a x68_64 compiler. If the compiler is called x86_64-mingw-gcc the prefix is x86_64-mingw-.

What is your 64 bit compiler called (path and name of gcc)?

Comment: BTW just to be clear, if you are developing for the computer you are on, just install a 64-bit toolchain as the default GCC in the first place. It will probably make your life easier, unless you really do want to manage multiple toolchains.